# How to make a silverlight treeview not highlight an item when you mouse over it

Tags: c#, silverlight

I know this involves a template some how, but I've done very little work with templates and I don't want to make a whole huge big new template just to accomplish this one thing. The default treeview in silverlight highlights an item when you mouseover it. Is there an easy way for me to make it not do this? I haven't found any other mention of it; most other questions I search for are people asking how to MAKE it highlight, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, you have to change the Default Template of the TreeView control to accomplish the desired behavior.

The following link provide you the TreeView Styles and Templates:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728671%28v=vs.95%29.aspx